# generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode9 Beta4

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

I'm using Xcode9 Beta4 and when I build my project I'm getting this error **generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)** I've clean the project and deleted drive data but still getting the same problem.[Please help me to remove this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9yEn.png)

Comment: Note: As per [Swift Bugs](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4254?focusedCommentId=22692&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-22692), I tried to disable "Precompile Bridging Header" in Build Settings at the error did go away, but then compiling never finishes.

Answer (score 9):

Xcode is unable to find the bridging header file in this case.

You can add the header path manually,

1. Find the path of your bridging header file
2. Search for `Bridging header` in xcode `build settings`
3. Edit the path like  `$(SRCROOT)/<projectname_folder>/<projectname>-Bridging-Header.h`

   `$(SRCROOT)` will give the dynamic path of your project in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested, (I had the same error) it is related to the bridging header, but I am still unable to confirm the real cause.

My fix: Removed the bridging header from the **Build Settings** tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my bridging header file had an extra extension at the end of the filename.  When I created the header file in Xcode, I typed a file name with a `.h` extension and Xcode added its own `.h` so the file on disk ended in `.h.h` but the name I entered in the build settings only had a single `.h`.  Renaming the file fixed the error.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to build settings and check the path of the info.plist file and bridging header file.

2.If not sure they are correct , from the left side drag and drop the files into respective fields .This creates the path automatically    .

3. Clean the project and build again .[image]